# Add Content to End of Article

Tags: joomla-3.4

I have created site with many pages/articles. I would like to add the following at the bottom of the article "You need an active subscription for this area".

Is there a way that I can add it without typing it out at the bottom of every single page?

Thanks

Carlton

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is via **override**, follow the step by step here:
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager

From here, select in Column **Component** > **com_content** > **article**

Find and edit the file in: 
`your_site/templates/your_template/html/com_content/article/default.php`

Add here your custom code or text.

Comment: Hi Neil I like your answer, however I am a little lost where you mention "publish the module to a module position below the main content (e.g. content-bottom-a on Gantry 4 templates)."

Comment: Basically, how you get to publish the module below the 'main content'? Cheers

Comment: I have updated my answer although your comments are posted under Alex's answer.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to do this is to create a Custom HTML module with the required text and then publish the module to a module position below the main content. Suitable module positions below the main content on the Gavick News2 template (for example) would be `mainbody_bottom` and `bottom1`. You can usually find the module position diagram on the [template developer demo website](https://demo.gavick.com/) as in the Gavick News2 example below:

[image: GK News2]

Alternatively, go to Extensions -> Templates -> Options and temporarily set "Preview Module Positions" to "Enabled". You can then view the module positions on your own website by browsing to http://www.keylooplabs.com/index.php?tp=1

You can control which pages the module is displayed on via the Menu Assignment tab in the module settings.