# How to Add Text at Bottom of All Joomla Articles

Tags: joomla-3.4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t0B5.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t0B5.png),

Can someone let me know how to add some text / syntax at the bottom of all joomla articles. So lets say I wanted to add xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx to end of each article as shown in the image would that be possible? I'm using joomla 3.4.1

Cheers

cpatte7372

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16953/add-content-to-end-of-article

Comment: man you have asked 3 times the same question

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/16959/120

Answer (score 2):

You can use template override to do this

Copy the `/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php` file to `/templates/{your template}/html/com_content/article/default.php`

Edit and seek for

```
    <?php echo $this->item->text; ?>
```

Then add your html after this line.

You can also modify the value of `$this->item->text` using php

Comment: tbh, this is a different question to the Batch Edit. That was resolved by @ffrewin, as a result I ended purchasing DB Replacer. This question asks how to make one sweeping change to every article. I want to add some thing like xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx which can only be viewed in source editor

Comment: Hello Jose, copying the default.php to my com_content/article/default.php sounds like it could potentially damage my site.

Comment: You must copy it from components/... To your templates/... Read my answer